# atoi() conversion error

Tags: c++, atoi

atoi() is giving me this error:

```
error C2664: 'atoi' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char' to 'const char *'
        Conversion from integral type to pointer type requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
```

from this line:
int pid = atoi( token.at(0) );
where token is a vector

how can i go around this?

Answer (score 12):

token.at(0) is returning a single char, but atoi() is expecting a string (a pointer to a char.) Either convert the single character to a string, or to convert a single digit char into the number it represents you can usually<sup>*</sup> just do this:

```
int pid = token.at(0) - '0';
```

<sup>* The exception is when the charset doesn't encode digits 0-9 in order which is extremely rare.</sup>

Comment: Any exception would also be non-compliant. The C++ standard [lex.charset] mandates that '0' - '9' have consecutive numerical values.

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to create a string:

```
int pid = atoi(std::string(1, token.at(0)).c_str());
```

... assuming that token is a std::vector of char, and using std::string's constructor that accepts a single character (and the number of that character that the string will contain, one in this case).

Comment: from what I remember, it's std::string(token.at(0), 1)

Comment: Other way around: number of characters, and the character. But you're right otherwise, Lev.

Answer (score 2):

Your example is incomplete, as you don't say the exact type of the vector. I assume it is std::vector<char> (that, perhaps, you filled with each char from a C string).

My solution would be to convert it again on char *, which would give the following code:

```
void doSomething(const std::vector & token)
{
    char c[2] = {token.at(0), 0} ;
    int pid   = std::atoi(c) ;
}
```

Note that this is a C-like solution (i.e., quite ugly in C++ code), but it remains efficient.

Answer (score 2):

```
const char tempChar = token.at(0);
int tempVal = atoi(&tempChar);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
stringstream ss;
ss << token.at(0);
int pid = -1;
ss >> pid;
```

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  using namespace std;

  vector<char> token(1, '8');

  stringstream ss;
  ss << token.at(0);
  int pid = -1;
  ss >> pid;
  if(!ss) {
    cerr << "error: can't convert to int '" << token.at(0) << "'" << endl; 
  }

  cout << pid << endl;
  return 0;
}
```